Why does the SHAP formula not state that |S| = |F|-1?
I recently read the paper "A unified approach to interpreting model predictions" by Scott M. Lundberg and Su-In Lee. In the paper, they establish that the Shapley value for the feature $i$ is defined as
\begin{equation}
\phi_i=\sum_{S \subseteq F \backslash\{i\}} \frac{|S| !(|F|-|S|-1) !}{|F| !}\left[f_{S \cup\{i\}}\left(x_{S \cup\{i\}}\right)-f_S\left(x_S\right)\right]    
\label{math:shapley}
\end{equation}
where $F$ is the set that contains all features, and $S$ is a subset of $F$ where the feature $i$ is removed ($S \subseteq F \backslash i$). I cannot find any clarification for why the following simplification is not performed in the formula when one feature is removed:
$|S| = |F|-1 \Longrightarrow \frac{|S| !(|F|-|S|-1) !}{|F| !}  = \frac{|F-1| !0 !}{|F| !} = \frac{1}{|F|}$
meaning that we can just write
\begin{equation}
\phi_i=\frac{1}{|F|}\sum_{S \subseteq F \backslash\{i\}} \left[f_{S \cup\{i\}}\left(x_{S \cup\{i\}}\right)-f_S\left(x_S\right)\right].    
\end{equation}
I cannot find this simplification anywhere and I am not sure why, but I suspect that I have somehow misunderstood the Shapley concept. Does anyone know if my simplification is wrong, and if so, why?

A key point to note about the Shapley Value is that it is also the average contribution feature $i$ makes to the fit metric/function $f()$ across all possible permutations of the $|F|$ features. Thus, more generally the Shapley Value is:
$$\phi_i = \frac{1}{|F|!}\sum_{p=1}^{|F|!} [f(x_{O_p \cup \{i\}}) - f(x_{O_p})]$$
Where $O_p$ is a permutation/ordered set of the features in $F$ not including $i$ up to the point at which $i$ is included in the model.
If it is the case that the order of inclusion for the features in $O_p$ is irrelevant for $f(O_p)$, as is usually the case for most models and fit metrics, then it is not necessary to represent the Shapley Value as a average across all permutations but a weighted average collapsing across identical values.
As an example of what I mean, consider one $O_p$ that is comprised of features $j$ and $k$ included in that order. For many models, the contribution $i$ makes when added to that $O_p$ will be the same as another $O_p$ where the order is reversed such that $k$ is first then $j$. Thus, the ordered nature of $O_p$ is irrelevant and we can consider all sets containing $j$ and $k$ to be an unordered subset of $F$ that doesn't contain $i$ or $S \subset F \setminus i$ as above. There will be $|S|!$ different permutations of those features in the model. There will also be $(|F| - |S| - 1)!$ permutations of features in the full set of permutations outlined previously that follow the inclusion of $i$. The total number of possible permutations of features for a specific unordered set $S$ that are included before $i$ is then $|S|!(|F| - |S| - 1)!$ or the numerator of the weight above.
The term $\frac{|S|!(|S| - |F| - 1)!}{|F|!}$ is then correct in that it reflects the number of ways the specific value $[f(x_{S \cup \{i\}}) - f(x_{S})]$ will arise in the data when $i$ when included at position $|S| + 1$ after all the features in $S$ have been included. Again, conceptually, that term is intended to represent how many times that specific function of the features is represented in the full set of permutations during averaging. This is also why the simplification in the in your post will not accurately reproduce the Shapley Value and why you have not found that simplification in the literature to date.
